URL with parameter only reaching IIS on localhost
CASE 1
OK
URL: https://10.0.0.21/myweb/webhome
IIS LOG:
2024-06-24 08:39:52 10.0.0.21 GET /myweb/webhome 443 - 10.0.0.21 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 14

OK
URL: https://my.domain.com/myweb/webhome
IIS LOG:
2024-06-24 08:40:02 10.0.0.21 GET /myweb/webhome 443 - 10.0.0.21 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 14

CASE 2
OK
URL: https://10.0.0.21/myweb/webhome?ABC=42
IIS LOG:
2024-06-24 08:41:12 10.0.0.21 GET /myweb/webhome ABC=42 443 - 10.0.0.21 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 14

FAILD
URL: https://my.domain.com/myweb/webhome?ABC=42
IIS LOG:
<EMPTY>

Comment
When using ?ABC=42 at the end of the url, the request only reaches IIS on localhost and in the Browser it says 403 Forbidden You dont have access to this recource. Localhost does work. Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Don't type error messages out using your words. People can only help if they see the original error messages, either copied from the original web page, or from a clear screen shot. Besides, you need to run iisreset to ensure cached items are written to log files, so the temporary emptiness isn't unexpected.

The Firewall was the problem,
it blocked URL-Parameters and also some of my requests werent properly redirected to https or at least came in to Port 80 in IIS
